# setting to default value if None

Tags: python

If I was trying to do

```
safe_value = dict_[key] if key in dict_ else default
```

a more concise way would be

```
safe_value =  dict_.get(key, default)
```

Is there something similar to shorten the following (in Python 3.11)?

```
safe_value = value if value is not None else default
```

Comment: If you specifically need to check `is not None`, and not generally *falsey*, then no.

Comment: `safe_value = default if value is None else value` is slightly shorter

Comment: @Guy `value or default` then, but that's not equivalent to OP's code!

Comment: I think this question should not be closed because the asker has give the code that the accepted answer in the [duplicate] post and after reading the other answers in the [duplicate] post, none of the results are shorter (concise) (in terms of characters) than what the asker has suggested. Some, such as using a function, which may be more concise depending on what the usage for the code (the number of times this is needed, thus function calls). The question may be related to [codegolf](codegolf.stackexchange.com) however this is not really a competition so probably not suitable to be migrated.

Comment: Since this question has been closed, I will write them here. From [this code golf tip for python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python/62#62), you can use `(value, default)[value is None]`. However this may be much less readable than the answer posted so depends what you value more (short in bytes or readable)

Answer (score 1):

You could always write your own function for it:

```py
def safe(value, default):
    return value if value is not None else default
```

Usage:

```py
>>> safe(4, 0)
4
>>> safe(None, 0)
0
```

Note however that this will always evaluate the `default` expression, whereas a ternary `value if value is not None else default` will not evaluate it when `value` isn't `None`. So it should probably only be used when `default` is a simple expression with no side-effects (e.g. a literal value, or a variable).